# How to get in tsql total number of hours inside a time range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Thanks in advance.

My question is I have a start time(2017-10-09 20:28:05.997) and end time(2017-10-10 05:37:12.413) on my table

I would like to check how many hours using tsql will fall between (2017-10-09 22:00:00.00) and (2017-10-10 06:00:00.000) this are constant.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
Declare @start_time datetime;
Declare @start_range datetime;
Declare @end_range datetime;
Declare @end_time datetime;

If @start_range < @start_time 
Begin
  Set @start_range =@start_time;
End

If @end_time  < @end_range 
Begin
  Set @end_range =@end_time;
End

Select datediff(hour, @start_range, @end_range)
```

In the range variables, you set the fixed range you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think `datediff()` does what you want.  Does this work?

```
select datediff(hour, starttime, endtime) as hours
```

Because `datediff()` only counts boundaries (hour boundaries are at the top of the hour), sometimes it is better to use a smaller unit and then do arithmetic.

For instance, decimal hours are pretty well approximated by:

```
select datediff(second, starttime, endtime) / (60 * 60.0) as decimal_hours
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I only need hours that would fall between 22:00 and 6:00